# Sorting an Array in Java

Tags: java, sorting

As a sample, I am developing a simple MySortedSet in java which implements SortedSet interface. It is backed up with a simple array which is E[] array.

I have several questions regarding that:

This is the class: (I am not writing entire code, instead of related parts)

```
public class MySortedSet<E> implements SortedSet<E>, Iterator<E> {

 private E[] array;
 private Comparator<? super E> _comparator;
 private int size = 0;
 private int capacity;

 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
 public MySortedSet() {
    this.capacity = 10;
    this.array = (E[]) new Object[this.capacity];
    // this.array = Array.newInstance(Class<E> var,int size);
    // We have to get Class<E> from outside caller.
 }
}
```

**Question 3:** There is a explanation for Constructor since this is a sorted set so it is assumed the elements are sorted:

> If this constructor is used to create the sorted set, it is assumed
>   that the elements are ordered using their natural ordering (i.e., E
>   implements Comparable).

It gets two different constructor. One is parameterless and the other one is accepting `Comparator<? super E>`.

```
public MySortedSet() {
    this.capacity = 10;
    this.array = (E[]) new Object[this.capacity];
    // this.array = Array.newInstance(Class<E> var,int size);
    // We have to get Class<E> from outside caller.
}

public MySortedSet(Comparator<? super E> comparator) {
    this._comparator = comparator;
}
```

If `comparator` is not passed in, natural ordering should be used but I am not really sure how to accomplish it as I need to get `Comparator` in some way to access `compare` method. Do you guys please recommend me a way to call it so I can call it while comparing in `sort` method to sort each element.

For whom they like to see whole code, please refer to this address: http://codepaste.net/4ucvsw it is not perfect but I am working on it.

**Question 4:** The code guide says :

> Because the fastest way to search for a particular item is to use a
>   binary search, you must ensure that the items in the collection are in
>   sorted order at all times. This won't be as hard to achieve as it may
>   seem. When you insert a new item, you can assume the array you are
>   inserting it into is already sorted. So all you need to do is find the
>   position in the array where the new item belongs, shift everything
>   greater than the new item one slot to the right, and insert the new
>   item. This is called insertion sort.

Here is the `sort` method logic. I am needed to make binary search to find where a new item belongs to so I can insert the new item in that place and move the other one slot to the right.

But I am not really sure how binary search will work for me here since I am not really sure what I need to find. I am given the item to add not the item to find. Instead what I think is to compare each element with the one I need to add and when I find the last smaller and first greater item, then I will get the first greater item's index, move them to the right and add new item at the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 3:**

The fact is that every collection works with a predefined comparator, which is implicitly defined on the `E`, so that every class that will be used to concretize the type parameter `E` should [`implement Comparable<E>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html). The compare method you are looking for natural ordering is the method

```
int compareTo(E other)
```

that must be implemented by the classes that you are going to use with your data structure. Since your work is not related to defining classes to be used with your collection but just the collection itself what you are going to do it to have

```
public class MySortedSet<E> ... {
    private Comparator<? super E> _comparator;

    public int innerCompare(E e1, E e2)
    {
      if (_comparator != null)
        return _comparator.compare(e1,e2);
      else
        return e1.compareTo(e2);
    }

    ...
```

So that you'll use a custom comparator when provided, the natural one otherwise.

Both `Comparable` and `Comparator` work by following the same principle but the first one, as the name states, is attached to a data class, so that it is its natural comparator. The latter, instead, is used because it allows you to define a custom way to sort elements which would be sorted in a different way according to natural ordering.

**Question 4:**

What it means is that, under the assumption of having a sorted array, you just must keep this constraint valid after every insertion and you will be allowed to do binary search when looking for items.

You must focus just on placing the elements at correct index (the item you have to add). The part of the statement related to finding elements must be interpreted in the following way:

> if you take care of keeping your array sorted, that can be done by ensuring that every element you add is placed in right position (eg with insertion sort), then you can apply binary search on the array when looking if an element is contained in the set.

This is true because, if the array is sorted, you can be sure that looking at the middle element of a section of the array will always point you to the right direction to see if another element is indeed contained in the list.

EG:

```
1, 2, 6, 11, 21, 30, 45
```

You need to check for 2, you can take element at index `size()/2 = 3`, which is `11`. Since your already know that the array is sorted and `2 < 11` you can just do the same thing recursively on the left half and so on.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer 3:**

"Natural ordering" means that the elements must implement [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) so that they can be compared without the use of a [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html). The tricky part about giving the caller a choice between `Comparable` elements and a `Comparator` is that you can't do compile time checking to make sure they fulfilled at least one of these requirements.

Java's [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) similarly exposes a constructor that takes a `Comparator` and others that don't. `TreeSet`'s contract is essentially to throw a `ClassCastException` if you try to insert an element that isn't a `Comparable` if you didn't provide the `TreeSet` with a `Comparator` when you created it. Whether you want to use this strategy or another one is up to you.

**Answer 4:**

Based on the quote's strategy, you should be able to use [`Arrays.binarySearch(Object[], Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.lang.Object%29) for this exact purpose. From that method's documentation:

> **Returns:** index of the search key, if it is contained in the array;
>   otherwise, `(-(insertion point) - 1)`. The insertion point is defined as
>   the point at which the key would be inserted into the array: the index
>   of the first element greater than the key, or `a.length` if all elements
>   in the array are less than the specified key. Note that this
>   guarantees that the return value will be >= 0 if and only if the key
>   is found.